# What do the following lines of code mean?

Tags: go

Can someone help me to understand the commented lines of code?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type myInt int

func (a myInt) add(b myInt) myInt {
    return a + b
}
func main() {
    num1 := myInt(5)        // mark - 1
    fmt.Println(num1)
    num2 := myInt(10)       // mark - 2
    fmt.Println(num2)
    sum := num1.add(num2)   // mark - 3
    fmt.Println("Sum is", sum)
}
```

Comment: The first two declare and initialize variables of type myInt (https://tour.golang.org/basics/13), the third calls the add method (https://tour.golang.org/methods/1).

Comment: Your trying to make the code block **bold** does not work inside a code snippet. You could just leave a comment right next to those very line.

Comment: The Tour  of Go explain the language. Work through it.

Answer (score 1):

```golang
type myInt int

func (a myInt) add(b myInt) myInt {
    return a + b
}

...

    num1 := myInt(5)
    num2 := myInt(10)
    sum := num1.add(num2)
```

Here, `type myInt int` is defining a type just like

```
type myStruct struct {
    ...
}
```

And `num1 := myInt(5)` is defining a variable of type `myInt`, you can also see as a typecast.

And `sum := num1.add(num2)` is just calling a `method` of `myInt` type.

Here are some references regarding this. 
- https://tour.golang.org/methods/3 
- https://gobyexample.com/methods